# Mesh appears normal in solid mode but looks weird in textured mode

Tags: mesh, texturing, draw-mode

I have Blender 2.49b and have this model:

[image]

When I change mode to Textured, the windows look weird:

[image]

When I go back to solid mode, it's normal, but the biggest problem is when I export the model, it looks like the image above. How can I fix this?

Comment: You probably won't get too may answers because you are using a version which is nolonger actively supported. Also the image from your first link appears to be broken.

Comment: I fixed the first image.. Yes, is not supported, but only this version is compatible with the game [OMSI]

Comment: What format do you need to export? Some export formats aren't enabled by default, you may need to enable them in the addons section of the preferences.

Comment: Looks like your normals are flipped around.

Comment: @sambler to DirectX [.x]

Comment: @GAMELASTER There is a directX exporter available in 2.68 but it isn't turned on by default, try enabling it (it's in User Preferences under Addons) and see if you can import into the game. The same tips for correcting normals apply to the newer versions.

Comment: @sambler hmm, i try it, thanx :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely cause would be the normals, that is which way the polygon is facing, the outer side is the one that has the texture drawn on it. In edit mode select all and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>. If that makes it worse try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to flip them the other way.

Worst case scenario you can select individual faces and flip the normals using Mesh->Normals->Flip (Flip normals is also available in the specials menu <kbd>W</kbd>)

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be an issue with the faces themselves rather than which mode you have selected.

I would first check to see if the faces are pointing in the wrong direction. 
First enable Draw Normal from the Mesh Tool Panel

[image]

If they are point the wrong direction then they can be flipped the correct direction using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>. See the [wiki docs - Face Normal](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Faces#Normals) for more information about flipping direction.

I would also check to see if these faces have been UV wrapped. In edit mode, select the faces in question. Open the UV Editor and if they have been uv'd then they should be visible for manipulating the UV layout. If not you will have to UV unwrap those faces.

You should also check to see if these faces have a texture associated with them. If they don't you will have to assign one.

At this stage if the format you are using allows it you can enable double sided.